# How to horizontally align ul to center of div?

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to center a `<ul>` inside a `<div>`. I tried the following

```css
text-align: center;
```

and

```css
left: 50%;
```

This is not working.

**CSS**:

```css
.container { 
    clear: both; 
    width: 800px; 
    height: 70px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container ul { 
    padding: 0 0 0 20px; 
    margin: 0; 
    list-style: none;
}

.container ul li { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

I want the `ul` to be centered inside the container.

Comment: I thought I would add to this question, the above can now be accomplished much easier with `Flex`.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Following is a list of solutions to centering things in CSS horizontally. The snippet includes all of them.

```css
html {
  font: 1.25em/1.5 Georgia, Times, serif;
}

pre {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

blockquote {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #e0f0d1;
}

blockquote > p {
  font-style: italic;
}

blockquote > p:first-of-type::before {
  content: open-quote;
}

blockquote > p:last-of-type::after {
  content: close-quote;
}

blockquote > footer::before {
  content: "\2014";
}

.container,
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.container::after,
blockquote::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container::after {
  content: ".container-" attr(data-num);
  z-index: 1;
}

blockquote::after {
  content: ".quote-" attr(data-num);
  z-index: 2;
}

.container-4 {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

/**
 * Solution 1
 */
.quote-1 {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/**
 * Solution 2
 */
.container-2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.quote-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

/**
 * Solution 3
 */
.quote-3 {
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/**
 * Solution 4
 */
.container-4 {
  position: relative;
}

.quote-4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/**
 * Solution 5
 */
.container-5 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>CSS: Horizontal Centering</h1>

  <h2>Uncentered Example</h2>
  <p>This is the scenario: We have a container with an element inside of it that we want to center. I just added a little padding and background colors so both elements are distinquishable.</p>

  <div class="container  container-0" data-num="0">
    <blockquote class="quote-0" data-num="0">
      <p>My friend Data. You see things with the wonder of a child. And that makes you more human than any of us.</p>
      <footer>Tasha Yar about Data</footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>

  <h2>Solution 1: Using <code>max-width</code> & <code>margin</code> (IE7)</h2>

  <p>This method is widely used. The upside here is that only the element which one wants to center needs rules.</p>

<pre><code>.quote-1 {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}</code></pre>

  <div class="container  container-1" data-num="1">
    <blockquote class="quote  quote-1" data-num="1">
      <p>My friend Data. You see things with the wonder of a child. And that makes you more human than any of us.</p>
      <footer>Tasha Yar about Data</footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>

  <h2>Solution 2: Using <code>display: inline-block</code> and <code>text-align</code> (IE8)</h2>

  <p>This method utilizes that <code>inline-block</code> elements are treated as text and as such they are affected by the <code>text-align</code> property. This does not rely on a fixed width which is an upside. This is helpful for when you don’t know the number of elements in a container for example.</p>

<pre><code>.container-2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.quote-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}</code></pre>

  <div class="container  container-2" data-num="2">
    <blockquote class="quote  quote-2" data-num="2">
      <p>My friend Data. You see things with the wonder of a child. And that makes you more human than any of us.</p>
      <footer>Tasha Yar about Data</footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>

  <h2>Solution 3: Using <code>display: table</code> and <code>margin</code> (IE8)</h2>

  <p>Very similar to the second solution but only requires to apply rules on the element that is to be centered.</p>

<pre><code>.quote-3 {
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}</code></pre>

  <div class="container  container-3" data-num="3">
    <blockquote class="quote  quote-3" data-num="3">
      <p>My friend Data. You see things with the wonder of a child. And that makes you more human than any of us.</p>
      <footer>Tasha Yar about Data</footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>

  <h2>Solution 4: Using <code>translate()</code> and <code>position</code> (IE9)</h2>

  <p>Don’t use as a general approach for horizontal centering elements. The downside here is that the centered element will be removed from the document flow. Notice the container shrinking to zero height with only the padding keeping it visible. This is what <i>removing an element from the document flow</i> means.</p>

  <p>There are however applications for this technique. For example, it works for <b>vertically</b> centering by using <code>top</code> or <code>bottom</code> together with <code>translateY()</code>.</p>

<pre><code>.container-4 {
    position: relative;
}

.quote-4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}</code></pre>

  <div class="container  container-4" data-num="4">
    <blockquote class="quote  quote-4" data-num="4">
      <p>My friend Data. You see things with the wonder of a child. And that makes you more human than any of us.</p>
      <footer>Tasha Yar about Data</footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>

  <h2>Solution 5: Using Flexible Box Layout Module (IE10+ with vendor prefix)</h2>

  <p></p>

<pre><code>.container-5 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}</code></pre>

  <div class="container  container-5" data-num="5">
    <blockquote class="quote  quote-5" data-num="5">
      <p>My friend Data. You see things with the wonder of a child. And that makes you more human than any of us.</p>
      <footer>Tasha Yar about Data</footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

### `display: flex`

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**Notes**:

- It’s not a hack
- [Browser support: flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

---

### `max-width` & `margin`

You can horizontally center a block-level element by assigning a fixed width and setting `margin-right` and `margin-left` to `auto`.

```
.container ul {
  /* for IE below version 7 use `width` instead of `max-width` */
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

**Notes**:

- No container needed
- Requires (maximum) width of the centered element to be known

---

### IE9+: `transform: translatex(-50%)` & `left: 50%`

This is similar to the quirky centering method which uses absolute positioning and negative margins.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

**Notes**:

- The centered element will be removed from *document flow*. All elements will completely ignore of the centered element.
- This technique allows *vertical* centering by using `top` instead of `left` and `translateY()` instead of `translateX()`. The two can even be combined.
- [Browser support: `transform2d`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

---

### IE8+: `display: table` & `margin`

Just like the first solution, you use auto values for right and left margins, but don’t assign a width. If you don’t need to support IE7 and below, this is better suited, although it feels kind of hacky to use the `table` property value for `display`.

```
.container ul {
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

---

### IE8+: `display: inline-block` & `text-align`

Centering an element just like you would do with regular text is possible as well. Downside: You need to assign values to both a container and the element itself.

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.container ul {
  display: inline-block;

  /* One most likely needs to realign flow content */
  text-align: initial;
}
```

**Notes:**

- Does not require to specify a (maximum) width
- Aligns flow content to the center (potentially unwanted side effect)
- Works kind of well with a dynamic number of menu items (i.e. in cases where you can’t know the width a single item will take up)

Comment: Thank you... the display css style fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @kleinfreund, using 'solution 3' worked for me on Firefox 29.0.1 and IE10.

Comment: @kleinfreund ! i am using chrome  39.0.2171.95  and when i do text-align:center on the main div the ul centers !! , so are these hacks really required for contemporary browsers ? Link: http://jsfiddle.net/8jsat2h9/ .

Comment: I wouldn't call these hacks. Maybe the last one is strange, but there may be occasions where you need it. What is your question?

Comment: @kleinfreund i have a feeling that you included the 4th solution , just for eye-candy :) as u mentioned it would require pre-fixes . the question i had is in my initial comment attached with a fiddle. but you don't really have to answer it , i kind of figured it out myself :D . great answer though ! thanks .

Comment: @Tenali_raman Thank you for the demo. I reworked it to show all 4 solutions side by side (and noticed, that solution 4 wasn't actually working). I still don't get your original question. What's the issue with that?

Comment: I'm putting text in a <ul> on top of an image, and only the 4th solution worked for me.

Comment: I use bootstrap and first method worked even without max-width, which is neat

Comment: I'm trying solution 5, but the `ul` is line wrapping so it looks like I have 3 columns.  Any idea why?

Comment: @JeffO'Neill I’m not sure what you mean. Do you have an example/code snippet?

Comment: @kleinfreund, I switched to #3 and that worked.  I just tried #5 again and it works now and I can't recreate what I mentioned in my previous comment.  Thanks for the great post!

Answer (score 18):

Make the left and right margins of your UL auto and assign it a width:

```
#headermenu ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 620px;
}
```

**Edit:** As kleinfreund has suggested, you can also center align the container and give the ul an inline-block display, but you then also have to give the LIs either a left float or an inline display.

```
#headermenu { 
    text-align: center;
}
#headermenu ul { 
    display: inline-block;
}
#headermenu ul li {
    float: left; /* or display: inline; */
}
```

Comment: The menu items (the anchors) in the `#headermenu` on the link the author provided have `float: left;` assigned.

Comment: @kleinfreund, yes, on his page they do, but not in the code snippet he pasted in the question.  It doesn't hurt to explicitly state this.

Comment: Maybe you should use the float as your example, because the menu items are not inline on his page, too.

Comment: @kleinfreund, fine.  I had the float in a comment, but I've switched it around now.

Answer (score 4):

```
ul {
width: 90%; 
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    left:5%;
}
```

Comment: explain what you did here!

Answer (score 1):

**You can check this solved your problem...**

```
    #headermenu ul{ 
        text-align: center;
    }
    #headermenu li { 
list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #headermenu ul li a{
        float: left;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/VCZgW/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
      text-align: center;
      list-style: inside;
    }
```