# UL will not align in center of div

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting my ul to be in the center of my div however this will work. The code keeps going to the left of the webpage even though I have tried to center it. I have tried a couple of different solutions and to no avail. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul class="links">
      <!--PHP code will return menu set in <li> and <a> tags-->
      <?php include "setMenu.php";?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    border: 1px black solid;
}

#nav ul{
    display: block-inline;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-image: url("../images/button_background.jpg");
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: center;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

#nav li:hover{
    color: black;
    background-image: url("../images/button_background_hover.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Add the source code, what the php return.

Comment: "<a href=\"login.php\"><li>Login</li></a><a href=\"#\"><li>Register</li></a><a href=\"#\"><li>News</li></a><a href=\"#\"><li>About</li></a>"

Comment: possible duplicate of [align UL to center of DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946284/align-ul-to-center-of-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#nav ul{
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

```
#nav ul{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4tnwjrag/2/

Example:

```css
#nav {
border: 1px black solid;
background:green;
}

#nav ul{
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
margin: 0px auto;
background:blue;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}

#nav li {
padding: 5px 5%;
display:table-cell;
width:120px;
margin-right: 5px;
background-image: url("../images/button_background.jpg");
color: white;
list-style:none;
border-radius: 3px;
position: center;
border: 1px black solid;
}

#nav li:hover{
color: black;
background-image: url("../images/button_background_hover.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
   <ul class="links">
      <!--PHP code will return menu set in <li> and <a> tags-->
       <li>zz</li>
       <li>zz</li>
       <li>zz</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: block-inline;` should be `display: inline-block;`.
There's no `block-inline` value for display. [Here is a list](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) of available values for that CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align center on your div and set padding to 0 on the ul like this:

```css
#nav {
    border: 1px black solid;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav ul{
    display: block-inline;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a similar question: [How to horizontally align ul to center of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946284/align-ul-to-center-of-div)

I chose to go with solution #2 and applied it to your elements, where

```
#nav {
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and here is a jsfiddle of the solution applied to your particular case: http://jsfiddle.net/7qd5bkse/

I had to make  a few tweeks to make it look like yours, but I hope this helps and should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution

```css
#nav {
  border: 1px black solid;
  text-align: center
}
#nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: white
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center
}
#nav li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="#">Menu One</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Two</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```