# how to center li elements in ul?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to display ul elements at the center of the page? I have looked at other similar questions within this site, I have tried to implement their way using text-align in my css file to shift elements to the center. However I dint get the desirable result. I also Have tried to use the margin which did center the elements in the middle of the page but I can press on the menu bottom when it accessed from mobile browser.

```
        <!--Top Menu Nav -->
           <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tech Experts</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <li><a href="#">Company</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Get In Touch</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <!--End Menu Nav -->

    //CSS Center Ul Elements
    #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .collapse>ul{
        text-align: center;
    }
#custom-bootstrap-menu     .collapse>ul{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946284/align-ul-to-center-of-div

Answer (score 1):

Margin auto centers elements in their container.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: IT did work.However, when I minimize the page to the mobile screen size I am not able to open the menu anymore

Comment: How did you implement the menu collapsing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header col-md-4 "><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tech Experts</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder col-md-4">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li><a href="#">Company</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Get In Touch</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Are you looking for this or any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

Give text-align:center to `<ul>` wrapper, eg. to div with class "collapse"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to center the elements using just margin.

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu .collapse>ul{
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE8+

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .collapse > ul {
  display: table;  
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list contains bullets, this will keep them close to the items

```
.collapse > ul > li{
    display:table;
    margin: auto;
}
```