# Centering things! Navigation bar and header

Tags: html, css

I am really new to coding. Formatting is always an issue with me and I spend lots of time looking at similar questions in here and reading tutorial etc and tried different things. I have the exact same code on one page and it seems center. However I can't get my items centered here or replicate. Once I have my header centered I would like my nav bar to be centered underneath. PLease help.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
  border: 2px white dotted;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 470px;
  padding: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.nav-pills li a {
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 589px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border-radius:0px;
  background-color: white;
  display:inline-block;
}
.nav-pills {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-centered">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-centered">
        <div class="box"> 
          <h2>lewis <br><span>Designs</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills"> 
            <li><a href="./home.html">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li> 
            <li><a href="./gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> 
            <li><a href="./contact">Contact</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the title: make .box width:100% and the h2 text-align:center.
To center the ul menu I followed the solution three: [align ul to center of div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16946321/4334348)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
  border: 2px white dotted;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%; // NEW WIDTH
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box h2 {
  text-align: center; // CENTER TITLE
}
.nav-pills li a {
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 589px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-pills {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: table; // SOLUTION 3
  margin: 0 auto; //
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-centered">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-centered">
        <div class="box">
          <h2>lewis <br><span>Designs</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="./home.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="./about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="./gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="./contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using Bootstrap. You can do what you want with a lot less markup.

```css
.nav-pills > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
    <h2>lewis <br><span>Designs</span></h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills text-center"> 
        <li><a href="./home.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li> 
        <li><a href="./gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> 
        <li><a href="./contact">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzxk9pe4/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this good for you? (please look at the snippet)

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}
.container {
max-width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px white dotted;
 border-radius: 15px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 display:inline-block;
}
.nav-pills li a {
 color: black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 3px;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 589px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 border-radius:0px;
 background-color: white;
 display:inline-block;
}
.nav-pills {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 text-align:center;
}
.center-box{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 391px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header" id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
            <div class="box">
              <h2>lewis                 <br />
                <span>Designs</span>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="row row-centered">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
              <div class='center-box'>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li>
                  <a href="./home.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you propose for the CSS part (beside a link) :) ?

Comment: It is in the answer and in the plunker. I do not understand your question. (I edited it to be more clear)

Comment: links can die and people have to go to another page to find out if answer is relevant or not. you can just turn everything here into a snippet ;)

Comment: First time I use this, I didn't notice that existed, thanks @GCyrillus :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of better semantic code to make it clear how this section is functioning and then simplify the code with built-in classes in Bootstrap, e.g., `text-center`.

```
  <header class="header text-center" id="header">
    <h1>lewis Designs</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="./home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="./gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="./contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

The only CSS needed to center the nav is this:

```
  nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

I'd definitely recommend familiarizing with documents pertaining to things like [utility classes in Bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/). You may not be able to do everything you want, but you can minimize the need to go markup heavy and create a bunch of classes that Bootstrap already has covered in various ways.

Comment: Thanks, i have been meaning to do that!