# How to center ul li list without knowing its width? (pagination)

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center

How to center this ul_li list without knowing its width? I need it because it width can be different in various situations.

And there is question, how to center this list and make it looks exactly the same, just centered?

margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto doesn't work. :<

```css
.pagination {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table;
}

.pagination ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.pagination ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-Ua-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

<div class="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li>
      &laquo;
    </li>
    <li>
      1
    </li>
    <li>
      2
    </li>
    <li>
      3
    </li>
    <li>
      4
    </li>
    <li>
      &raquo;
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use <center></center> around the <ul>

Comment: @ShubhamKundu nope. Anyway - it is centered in my Chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally align ul to center of div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946284/how-to-horizontally-align-ul-to-center-of-div)

Comment: @Shubham Kundu I would downvote you 10 times if that was an answer

Comment: @mplungjan, I never know what will be width! It is not trouble. See ["How do I center align horizontal <UL> menu?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu) also.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` on li **instead of** `float:left` and give the parent `text-align:canter`.

Here is the work around.

```css
.pagination {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.pagination ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
}

.pagination ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li>
      &laquo;
    </li>
    <li>
      1
    </li>
    <li>
      2
    </li>
    <li>
      3
    </li>
    <li>
      4
    </li>
    <li>
      &raquo;
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I see no difference from the original in Chrome

Comment: @mplungjan This is a better approach I suppose ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `padding:0` inside `.pagination ul`. nothing else.

Please check this.

```css
.pagination {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table;
}

.pagination ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}

.pagination ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-Ua-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

<div class="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li>
      &laquo;
    </li>
    <li>
      1
    </li>
    <li>
      2
    </li>
    <li>
      3
    </li>
    <li>
      4
    </li>
    <li>
      &raquo;
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```