# How should I properly implement a .png logo as part of a center-justified navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I am using Apple's navigation toolbar as my design aesthetic/goal as everything is center justified and the logo included as part of that justification.

Here's how I have it setup currently...

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="Images/Logo.png"  alt="DIVINITAL"width="35" height="35"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</header>
</body>
```

This, however, proves difficult for me to properly edit the logo alongside the ul items on the navbar. For some reason when I begin to style them accordingly, both widths have to be set to 100% for the alignment to workout but that obviously isn't allowed as they just move to two separate lines (the logo and the ul items on the nav bar...

So is there a better way to handle this? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally align ul to center of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946284/how-to-horizontally-align-ul-to-center-of-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You can easily do it using flex. There's a [good tutorial that explains how to use flex.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Look at the following example, and see for yourself how flex can easily achieve what you're looking for:

```css
header {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 44px;
}

.logo > img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: auto 20px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1
}

nav > ul {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto 20px;
}

nav > ul > li {

}

nav a {
  color: inherit
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-icon-social-media/512/099310-feedburner-logo.png" alt="DIVINITAL">
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</header>
```

The most important rules I used here were (flex rules):

- display: flex
- justify-content
- align-items